# Creating a model record for a database

Tags: php, object-oriented

I'm trying to expand my use of classes and better understand how/when to use them. Please review the code and let me know if I'm on the right track or where I need to make improvements. For example, should I remove the database call from the class, why or why not?

```
<?php
class Model{

    private $_db;

    private $first;
    private $last;
    private $gender;
    private $birthYear;
    private $agency;
    private $picture;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function add_model(){
        $statement = $this->_db->prepare("insert into models (first_name, last_name, gender, birth_year, agency, picture) values (:first, :last, :gender, :birth_year, :agency, :picture)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gender = VALUES(gender), birth_year=VALUES(birth_year), agency=VALUES(agency), picture=VALUES(picture)");

        $statement->bindParam(':first', $this->first);
        $statement->bindParam(':last', $this->last);
        $statement->bindParam(':gender', $this->gender);
        $statement->bindParam(':birth_year', $this->birthYear);
        $statement->bindParam(':agency', $this->agency);
        $statement->bindParam(':picture', $this->picture);

        $result = $statement->execute();
        if ($result){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should not know anything about how it gets created, that is what a repository is for. What if at some point in the future you changed from a database to a REST API? Now all of your models are invalid. If you use a repository, you could just add a new repository for the new API and the models are none-the-wiser.

So your model should just be this (notice I changed the name of the class, you should use descriptive names):

```
class PersonModel{

    private $first;
    private $last;
    private $gender;
    private $birthYear;
    private $agency;
    private $picture;

    public function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then you have a repository:

```
class PersonRepository {

    private $_db;

    public function __construct($db){
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function create($person){
        $statement = $this->_db->prepare("insert into models (first_name, last_name, gender, birth_year, agency, picture) values (:first, :last, :gender, :birth_year, :agency, :picture)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gender = VALUES(gender), birth_year=VALUES(birth_year), agency=VALUES(agency), picture=VALUES(picture)");

        $statement->bindParam(':first', $person->first);
        $statement->bindParam(':last', $person->last);
        $statement->bindParam(':gender', $person->gender);
        $statement->bindParam(':birth_year', $person->birthYear);
        $statement->bindParam(':agency', $person->agency);
        $statement->bindParam(':picture', $person->picture);

        $result = $statement->execute();
        if ($result){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function read($id) {
        //...
    }

    public function list() {
        //...
    }

    public function update($person) {
        //...
    }

    public function delete($person) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This keeps your database layer separate from your data layer and separate from your presentation layer. The more separation you can do here, the better off you are going to be when it comes to updating and maintaining this code.

I would recommend a good read through [SOLID principles](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074) to get an idea.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the code I wrote was ok, but you're saying it's better to split it into two parts. I think I understand why you're saying that and this is exactly the kind of feedback I was hoping for. Basically, if I were to change from MySQL to MongoDB this will make that transition much easier? Thanks so much for taking the time to help me understand better practices. I also greatly appreciate the reference you supplied, I will take a read and try to comprehend all this more. Without sounding too naive,  this leads me to MVC?

Comment: Yes, it can lead you to MVC since you have taken care of the "M" part without dictating how the controller gets the model. It helps make your transition easier because you don't have to change tested, proven code and it abides by the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: One last question as it pertains to your recommended splitting. Should those two classes be placed in the same class.php file, or is it better practice to have them in their own files?

Comment: I would prefer them in separate files, makes them easier to track in source control (which you should be using, even if for fun or learning).

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology of `Model` for this class is not really appropriate.  The terminology of `Model` is oftentimes tied to a (usually abstract) class in an application meant to provide certain data persistence behaviors to inheriting classes.  Even if you are intending to use this class to store a model (the occupation), you should still class the class something else like `Person`, `Client`, or similar that might be appropriate and less ambiguous.

---

Think about validating requests against the object more stringently.

For example,  this code that you use in your get/set magic methods:

> ```
>     if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
>         return $this->$property;
>     }
> ```

Might better be:

```
    if (!property_exists($this, $property)) {
        throw new OutOfBoundsException(
            'Property "' . $property . '" does not exist.'
        );
    }        
    return $this->$property;
```

This way you can let the caller know that they are trying to access the object in an invalid manner such that they might do something about it.  Your current code just silently fails without returning anything to the caller.

Similarly, in your constructor, you would seem to be passing a PDO object.  Enforce this with a type hint, so you are guaranteed to get a properly set up PDO object passed to this class.

---

```
public function __construct(PDO $pdo)
```

Consider naming your property `$pdo` to clearly represent to someone reading this code that this is what you are working with.

---

You do nothing to enforce that your object is set-up prior to making the database insert.  Right now a caller can instantiate this class and then try to make an insert before having set any properties. If the caller already had this information, why make them do something like this:

```
$person = new Person($pdo);
$person->first = ...;
$person->last = ...;
$person->gender = ...;
...
$person->create();
```

As opposed to something like:

```
$fields = [
    'first' => ...,
    ...
];
$person = PersonProvider::create($fields, $pdo);
```

At least with this approach you have a single point of entry to this required data such that you can perform appropriate validation before attempting a DB insert.

Your current approach of using magic getter/setter and setting of object properties eliminates your ability to validate the data being set on these fields before insert.

Note that I also used a static method call here.  I honestly don't see a use case for you to have to instantiate an object in order to then perform a database insert.  Your use case seems more aligned to provider or factory pattern usage.

---

Really think about whether magic getters/setters are what you want here. As noted above there are a lot of trade-offs in terms ability to validate data, make properties truly private, etc. that come with giving property-style access to protected/private properties through magic methods.

Again for your use case here, I don't know why the properties wouldn't just be public, because that is exactly how you are treating them.

---

Don't mix snake_case and camelCase in your own code as you are doing here in your property and method names.  I know PHP is not consistent in it's usage, but that doesn't mean you shouldn't be within your own code.

---

Your database operations just assume happy path.  You need to handle and log errors and/or throw exceptions for cases when `prepare()`, `execute()` and similar fail.